# Failed to read correct date from excel (oledb)

Tags: c#, excel, date, oledb

We are trying to automate some of the processes that our done daily, for this we have made some Excel files which store the instruction for these processes. In a few such excel files we are using **=TODAY()** function to populate the cell with today's date.

Now while trying to read these excel files, I am not able to get the correct date in the datatable if excel is not opened at least once on a particular date. The date picked is from the last time the excel file was opened. This is causing a major problem while automating the problem at hand.

**I would want to know if this can be achieved using OLEDB drivers and if not what other options are there?**

This is the code for reading from the excel, the datasource is constructed at runtime.

```
        private string excelObject = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";

        public DataTable GetSchema()
        {
            DataTable dtSchema = null;
            if (this.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) this.Connection.Open();
            dtSchema = this.Connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            return dtSchema;
        }

        public DataTable ReadTable(string tableName, string criteria)
        {

            try
            {
                DataTable resultTable = null;
                if (this.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    this.Connection.Open();
                    onReadProgress(10);

                }
                string cmdText = "Select * from [{0}]";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria))
                {
                    cmdText += " Where " + criteria;
                }
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format(cmdText, tableName));
                cmd.Connection = this.Connection;
                OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                onReadProgress(30);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                onReadProgress(50);

                adpt.Fill(ds, tableName);
                onReadProgress(100);

                if (ds.Tables.Count == 1)
                {
                    return ds.Tables[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Table Cannot be read");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't rely on functions/macros being run when you read the excel sheet with the OLEDB dataprovider. If you need that you'll need to open the excel sheet, for example by Excel interop but that kind of defeats the use of the OLE Data provider.

Comment: Yeah so what do you suggest? Move to interop and get rid of oledb

Comment: do you run this on a server or on a desktop that has excel installed?

Comment: On a desktop machine with excel installed